# How to tell how much of a video has been watched in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, analytics

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to tell how much of a video of mine has been watched. Something like, most people got to 50% of it, or most got to 90% of it and so on. Anyway to tell from the data available?

Comment: May be here have a look at this http://google.about.com/od/googleblogging/qt/YouTubeInsightQ.htm whether this gets you with some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YouTube analytics](https://www.youtube.com/analytics?o=U) has estimates on how much of a video was viewed. Bear in mind that these are rough estimates.

Comment: Where? I don't see that data?

Comment: did you click the link I put on youtube analytics?

Comment: I've been looking through the analytics for the last five days, I don't see it?